# User privileges

Tags: geoserver, security

My query is just about security level 
How can a layer be secured with username and password only that user can see that layer?

And if other user logged in but access is not given to him for that layer 
He should not  see the layer for which he was not assigned. But if I assigned group layers then it differently assigned for different user but all the layers are shown in all users. How can I hide those layers?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation covers this:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/layer.html

What you are looking for is *catalog mode=hide*, which is default.